# Переход на предыдущий шаг с помощью асинхронных функций

Tags: python, asyncio, aiogram-3.x

Мне нужно в телеграмм боте на aiogram 3 ввести данные паспорта (допустим, это будет 8 цифр) и проверить, есть ли в базе данных бота эти цифры (хранится в виде списка). Если есть, то поприветствовать и перейти на следующий шаг, если нет - вернуться к вводу.

Подскажите, как с помощью асинхронных функций сделать так, чтобы при вводе неверных данных возвращало на предыдущий шаг?

Comment: https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-3.x/examples/finite_state_machine.py

Comment: Подскажите, а как проверить введенные пользователем цифры?

@router.message(Form.passport_process, F.text in passport_list)
async def passport_finished(message: Message):
    await message.reply('Введеные паспортные данные верны. Продолжим. ')